# python calling oracle function ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: python, oracle, ora-00904

I am writing some Python code to call a function on a Oracle server.
This is the query string, copied directly from PyDev:

```
 select * from table( DQA.getFieldCount_E( 'BBG',  'PX_LAST', '22-Apr-2015',  '23-Apr-2015'  ) )
```

It runs fine within Toad and returns the expected results.
I know am connected to Oracle because I run other queries within my Python code that return correct results.  DQA is my schema.  I have tried without DQA, but get the same result.

I do not see my error.
Your kind assistance is requested.

KD

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the only thing that could be raising this error is that the user you are connected in TOAD has permissions to access this object (DQA.getFieldCount_E) and the user you are connected in Python doesn't.